# IdentityServer4 and ASP.Net Identity: Adding additional claims

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I'm trying to use IdentityServer4 with ASP.Net Identity Core providing a user store. I've loosely followed this guide: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4, and have gotten to a point where I can register and authenticate users locally using ASP.Net Identity.

My problem is that I add some claims on registration:

```
var createUserResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

if (createUserResult.Succeeded)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "user"),
        new Claim("test-claim", "loremipsum")
    };

    await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, new AuthenticationProperties());
    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl ?? "~/");
}
```

These are saved correctly, and I can see them in the database. However once I login, the user object only has the following claims:

- sub
- name
- auth_time
- idp
- amr

Looking online, it seems that I need to override the UserClaimsPrincipalFactory and register this implementation with the DI container:

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> options) : base(userManager, roleManager, options)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        ((ClaimsIdentity) principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("yolo", "swag"));

        return principal;
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("yolo", "swag"));

        return identity;
    }
}
```

Registered in the DI container as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

My understanding is that this custom principal factory should add the claims I want to the User object, but this doesn't happen. I can see the custom claims principal factory is instantiated using a breakpoint in the constructor, but the `GenerateClaimsAsync` function is never called.

IdentityServer and ASP.Net identity are registered as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer(config =>
    {
        config.PublicOrigin = _configuration.PublicOriginUrl;
    })
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseNpgsql(
            _sqlConnectionString,
            sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationsAssembly));
    })
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseNpgsql(
            _sqlConnectionString,
            sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationsAssembly));
    })
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

My custom user claims principal factory is registered after this section. Looking at the `AddAspNetIdentity` extension method [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/78d1da20c8107a86110bdeb64595ebb15f2d2e4e/src/IdentityServerBuilderExtensions.cs#L33), I can see it seems to register some sort of custom user claims principal factory, but I don't understand the implementation code well enough to work out exactly what's happening.

How can I implement a custom user claims principal factory such that I could do something like this in a view?

```
// "yolo" is a custom claim
@User.FindFirst("yolo")
```

Comment: I've looked at the `AddAspNetIdentity` extension method again, and I now understand that the `UserPrincipalClaimsFactory` implementation that I give is passed into IdentityServer's `UserClaimsFactory<TUser>` class, and this class doesn't have a `GenerateClaimsAsync` method. However, I'm not sure why this stops my implementation's `GenerateClaimsAsync` being called, even if I specifically re-register it in the DI container after adding IdentityServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this out (at least, in a way that satisfies my requirements). The logic that performed the login in the quickstart project looked like this:

```
...
if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password)) {
    await _events.RaiseAsync(
        new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName));


    AuthenticationProperties props = null;
    if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin) {
        props = new AuthenticationProperties {
            IsPersistent = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
        };
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, props);
    ...
}
```

By looking at the [extension methods](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/Extensions/HttpContextAuthenticationExtensions.cs) that IdentityServer4 adds to the HttpContext, I found that there were several that accept an array of claims.

I modified the login logic in my account controller:

```
...
var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, props, userClaims.toArray());
...
```

This successfully adds all the user's claims from the database to the current session. From here I was able to select only the claims I wanted, and pass an array of these instead.

Now that the desired claims are stored as part of the session, I'm able to call `@User.FindFirst("yolo")` from a view, or other controllers, as I require.

Comment: The extension methods link is dead now.  I'm not seeing these HttpContext extension methods that take a userClaims array.  What package are those in?

Comment: I think those extension methods that accept claims are gone in the latest version of identityserver4.  I'm looking for another way to add the claims.

Answer (score 2):

I also implemented similar functionality to set claims for a user.

```
Claim claim = new Claim(claimType, claimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String);
IdentityResult result = await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);
```

This add the Claims for the particular user in AspNetUserClaims table

[image]

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager** provides the inbuilt feature for Authentication.

This also automatically creates claims for user when logged in.
Following is a sample login using **SignInManager**

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AppUser appUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.Email);
            if (appUser != null)
            {
                await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(appUser, login.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                    return Redirect(login.ReturnUrl ?? "/");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(login.Email), "Login Failed: Invalid Email or password");
        }
        return View(login);
    }
```

After user is successfully logged in we can access all the claims in view using **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageBase.User**

Following is the sample code to retrieve all the claims:

```
     <h2>Claim details</h2>
     <ul>
        @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
        {
           <li><strong>@claim.Type</strong>: @claim.Value</li>
        }
     </ul>
```

> I followed this tutorial for Identity claims, where it includes managing custom claims as well

1. https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-claims/
2. https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnet-core-identity/